# Im trying to clear AsynStorage on logout

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

Im developing an app using react native and im running into this issue with AsyncStorage. I store the user data on login, and then I get the data on the main page. I simply want to display the users name in a small welcome message, then if the user signs out, I need to clear the storage and then get the storage of the next user signing in on the device and display their name.

The issue is the first time I sign in the users name does not display, only when I sign out and back in does the name display. Not only this, but it seems it keeps the name of the last person signed in and diplays that name the next time a sign in occurs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the main code where I get and display the username

````
    AsyncStorage.getItem('user_data', (err, result) => {
        console.log(result);
        var userdata = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(userdata);
        firstname = userdata.firstName;
        lastname = userdata.lastName;
    });

    const history = useHistory();
    const doLogout = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        history.push('/');
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('user_data', (err, result) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Welcome {firstname} </Text>
            <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.loginbut}
                    activeOpacity={.5}
                    onPress={doLogout}
                >
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignOutAlt} size={20} style={{ color: '#ffffff' }} />
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white' }}> Sign Out </Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
     );

} export default MainUI```
````

Comment: you can use await AsyncStorage.clear();

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
async removeItemValue(key) {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
        return true;
    }
    catch(exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it's better to use `redux` or `context` to store user data during the process running if you want to clear it after logging out.

`AsyncStorage` is something like you want to store some data after user exit the process.

Like the logging email or some app setting.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the AsyncStorage completely.

```
try {
    await AsyncStorage.clear();
} catch(e) {
    console.log(err);
}
```